# Can NIR minus Red be used instead of NDVI with Drone Imagery

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, remote-sensing, pix4d

I have some CIR imagery collected by a vendor using a Cannon Powershot S110 NIR, from an eBee fixed wing platform, about 400 ft AGL. All images were stitched together by the vendor in Pix4D. I want to use it to calculate NDVI for a change detection project in a small riparian corridor. A cursory visual inspection of the NDVI values looks about right, except I'm getting *very* high values in areas where there are shadows. The red band in these areas is picking up very little visible light, and many more times the amount of NIR.

I've read that NIR minus Red has been used instead of NDVI for drone imagery with this problem, but am not finding much literature on it. It seems like if the red band is compromised, this method is unlikely to produce much more reliable results.

Is this is a viable option?

If not, what other approaches might I try?

Comment: The NIR - Red is commonly known as the Red Edge (RE). Its a non-normalized version of the NDVI and measures the difference between the absorption of the red due to photosynthesis and reflection of the NIR (due to plant structure). It's similar to but not a direct replacement for NDVI. One approach may be to mask out shadows before you compute the RE or NDVI, as shadows will generally not contain useful information anyway

Comment: Can you please back up the assertion that the red band is commonly know as red edge? It has always been my understanding that the red edge band is located in the spectrum between the red band and the NIR band, without overlap. This covers the portion of the spectrum where reflectance drastically increases from the red towards the NIR asymptote. Given this, I do not understand your comment.